# c# How can count values per listbox item ?

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, count

In my form1, I have a listbox which has a list of items, call them forms. On the same form i have 12 textboxes, each form can have a maximum of 12 reports assigned to it, these reports will displayed in the textboxes.

How do i go through each listbox items(forms) checking how many reports have been assigned to it based on the textbox and displaying the count next to the homeform in the listbox.

i have written the method below which is called as soon as my form loads, but i am using the database to figure out the count, but the count gets me to total rather than count for each, is there any way to refine this or a better solution?

```
    public void countValues()
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var s in listBox1.Items)
        {
            var forms = s;

            var HomeForms = (FormItems)forms;

            foreach (DataSet1.xAnalysisUsageRow anuse in myDataSet.xAnalysisUsage)
            {
                var defNull = anuse.Isxanu_DefaultNull();
                if (!defNull)
                {
                    if (HomeForms.types.xlib_ID == anuse.xanu_Use)
                    {
                        count++;

                        var id = HomeForms.types.xlib_ID;
                        var library = myDataSet.xspGetAnalysisUsageTypes.FindByxlib_ID(id);
                        var libName = library.xlib_Desc;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your count variable should be initialized under first foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .length in the back end code, returns the number of items in the list